# equivalent data structure of LinkedHaspMap in guava or apache commons lang

Tags: java, type-conversion, linkedhashmap

I have a LinkedHashMap based on "Double" data types.

```
LinkedHashMap<Double, Double> meetingRecord;
```

I want it to be in primitive data type

```
LinkedHashMap<double, double> meetingRecord;
```

As far as I know from different search, Java by default has no such data structure available and I need to use something from  `guava-libraries` or `commons lang`

Please help, what should be used, i am really stuck.

Comment: Generic types need to be Objects. Can't you just use `Double.doubleValue` from your `Collection` objects or auto-unboxing?

Comment: The problem is that the below function of JRI: "re.assign" does not accept an array of Doubles, it requires double array. And I don't want to use loop to convert from Double to double as my program becomes very slower. LinkedHashMap<Double, Double> meetingHistory = this.meetingRecord.get(otherHost);                             re.assign("dd", meetingHistory.values());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your comment you state that you don't want to iterate through your values and convert from `Double` to `double`, but given the way that Java handles wrappers and primitives there really is no escaping that computation.

Whatever library you use to go from a collection of wrappers (objects) to an array of primitives, it will have to ask each wrapper object for the primitive value, essentially looping through the collection.

Having said that, Guava does this very nicely with:

```
double[] arrayOfDoubles = Doubles.toArray(meetingHistory.values());
```

Comment: Thank you. So this means, there isn't any data structure for collections available in any available library that directly deals with primitive types (such as LinkedHashMap<double, double> meetingRecord;)

Comment: Precisely. Since all collections (and generics) deal in Objects and primitives are not Objects, they will always have to be wrapped. If you want to work with primitives then you are restricted to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Commons Primitives (http://commons.apache.org/primitives/). However, you'd have to really, really care about performance to bother.